# Umbraco Deploy, is it possible to Rollback a published content

Tags: deployment, umbraco, rollback

in Umbraco Deploy, is it possible to publish (promote content and templates & publish them on the destination environment),

and then rollback the changes completely using Umbraco Deploy? (If some crisis is detected)

- I am refereeing to an on-prem Umbraco installations (ver. 8 and above)
- This is not a question about restore (pulling content from production to dev environments), but a desire to completely reverse the promotion (content deploy) action in the production environment,
- if the answer is NO, then - is there any third-party product that knows how to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a rollback feature on all content bulit-in to the backoffice, so you'd need to log in and do it manually. Not sure if Deploy or any other tool like it can roll back stuff, but I don't think so :-/

Comment: thanks but i am looking for a batch like operation (to perform the action at once), and also from DevOps (not manually from UI)

Answer (score 3):

The Umbraco rollback feature isn't granular enough for you to be like "this specific value change was done by admin/system, this other value change was done by editor". It saves/publishes the whole node as is, and the whole node is a "version".

Given that you want to publish changes on X number of nodes, and then later you want to roll back those changes, who knows how many newer versions exist on any of the affected nodes? So you can't just roll back one version, you'd need it to be timestamped somehow. And then you run the risk of deleting who knows how much content that might only exist on the environment you are rolling back.

So no, even if you yourself for instance structure your content in a highly, highly modular way where all "pages" are built by picking reusable "components" that you then publish via Deploy or whatever, there isn't anything built in to those tools to allow you to roll back versions. At least not to my knowledge.

That part shouldn't be all that difficult to do via an API controller, though. You could call an endpoint with a list of node ID's and a timestamp. Then for each node you'd need to delete versions newer than timestamp value (https://apidocs.umbraco.com/v9/csharp/api/Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.IContentService.html#Umbraco_Cms_Core_Services_IContentService_DeleteVersions_System_Int32_DateTime_System_Int32_). But it still requires a quite special content structure :-/

Comment: thank you for the very elaborated explanation, i will try the solution using the API you mentioned, but since delete is only a "ONE WAY" direction, is it possible using the API to also "undelete" a version somehow say using export / import only to that node (so i can apply the requested content version upon demand) ?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe if you get all the versions of the node and determine yourself which one should be rolled back to (by date), you might be able to just roll back to said versions via https://apidocs.umbraco.com/v9/csharp/api/Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.IContentService.html#Umbraco_Cms_Core_Services_IContentService_Rollback_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_System_Int32_ ? Could be wrong, but I think that would then create a *new* version with the *old* content? Thus not deleting anything?

Comment: @flyWithMe I'm curious - did you manage to get something working? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Backup Umbraco db before deploy and restore backup if you want to rollback.  If using devops then the rest (media, templates etc) is in the code deploy which you can easily rollback.

That would be the best and pretty much only way!

Comment: restore will omit runtime changes happened over time, and full restore would not allow separated changes to be rolled back, isn't there a more modular way?

Comment: I was assuming a content freeze would be in place.

Comment: first thanks for the answer, content freeze can occur on the source environment before promotion, but i wanted to have some artifact that i can re-run to get some content object to go back to its previous state/version

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at uSync Complete?

Comment: I don't think uSync can roll back content :-/

Comment: yes i have, unfortunately it cannot promote single content items and haven't seen a rollback option

Comment: uSync Complete (payable version) can promote single items.